# Cuda Debugging on Windows with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cuda, vscode-debugger

I want to debug my Cuda program with Visual Studio Code, and especially the GPU code because I can already debug the CPU code with the MSVC debugger(`cppvsdbg`). I know it can be done on Windows because there is this feature in Visual Studio 20XX.

I have installed:

- NSight extension
- Windows C++ Compiler (MSVC)
- Cuda Toolkit

What `type` do I need in my VS Code `launch.json`?

Right now I have selected this: `"type": "cppvsdbg"`. Every Tutorial suggests `cuda-gdb` but this only works for Linux

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76186047/how-to-debug-cuda-in-vscode-on-windows

Comment: Mine was the first but yes

Answer (score 1):

As answered in a comment on [How to debug CUDA in VSCode on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76186047/how-to-debug-cuda-in-vscode-on-windows)

This is an unsupported combination. I think sadly, we're limited to Visual Studio on Windows.